# Save an attachment from a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my bot download and save locally the attachments sent in the command (

see the attachment:
[image: see the attachment]

is it possible because the only thing I could find is this and it doesn't work as I wanted:

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    files = []
    for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:
        fp = BytesIO()
        await attachment.save(fp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont use BytesIO as that's meant to be use in memory, just add the filename you wish

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    files = []
    for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:
        # fp = BytesIO()
        await attachment.save(attachment.filename)
```

In this case i used the same filename as the attachment.